# Currency exchange app

Tags: javascript, finance, react.js, state

I'm making a currency exchange app, it works as follows:

User types in on desired currency input and the rest of the input fields change with state based on the currency value from the input used, I'm providing the main component (container), but this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4wq1pynv1w/) has a working demo.

1. I need some help or guidance on how to `setState` in a cleaner way probably with a loop, map or a new function.
2. Any help on how to create my `CURRENCIES` in a better way, considering that maybe someday the API I'm using will add an extra currency, and right now I would have to add it manually.
3. Considering point #2 mentioned above, I guess I will also need to improve my switch statement to adapt to the API growing in currencies.

This is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4wq1pynv1w/).

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import SingleInput from "./SingleInput.js";

import fetchedCurrencies from "./data.json";

const CURRENCIES = [
  { name: "MXN" },
  { name: "USD", value: fetchedCurrencies[0]["bm:Obs"][0].$.OBS_VALUE },
  { name: "USDFix", value: fetchedCurrencies[1]["bm:Obs"][0].$.OBS_VALUE },
  { name: "EUR", value: fetchedCurrencies[2]["bm:Obs"][0].$.OBS_VALUE },
  { name: "CAD", value: fetchedCurrencies[3]["bm:Obs"][0].$.OBS_VALUE },
  { name: "JPY", value: fetchedCurrencies[4]["bm:Obs"][0].$.OBS_VALUE },
  { name: "GBP", value: fetchedCurrencies[5]["bm:Obs"][0].$.OBS_VALUE }
];

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      MXN: "",
      USD: "",
      USDFix: "",
      EUR: "",
      CAD: "",
      JPY: "",
      GBP: ""
    };
  }

  handleCurrencyInput = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    switch (name) {
      case "USD":
        this.setState({
          MXN: value * CURRENCIES[1].value,
          USD: value,
          USDFix: value * CURRENCIES[1].value / CURRENCIES[2].value,
          EUR: value * CURRENCIES[1].value / CURRENCIES[3].value,
          CAD: value * CURRENCIES[1].value / CURRENCIES[4].value,
          JPY: value * CURRENCIES[1].value / CURRENCIES[5].value,
          GBP: value * CURRENCIES[1].value / CURRENCIES[6].value
        });
        break;

      case "USDFix":
        this.setState({
          MXN: value * CURRENCIES[2].value,
          USD: value * CURRENCIES[2].value / CURRENCIES[1].value,
          USDFix: value,
          EUR: value * CURRENCIES[2].value / CURRENCIES[3].value,
          CAD: value * CURRENCIES[2].value / CURRENCIES[4].value,
          JPY: value * CURRENCIES[2].value / CURRENCIES[5].value,
          GBP: value * CURRENCIES[2].value / CURRENCIES[6].value
        });
        break;

      case "EUR":
        this.setState({
          MXN: value * CURRENCIES[3].value,
          USD: value * CURRENCIES[3].value / CURRENCIES[1].value,
          USDFix: value * CURRENCIES[3].value / CURRENCIES[2].value,
          EUR: value,
          CAD: value * CURRENCIES[3].value / CURRENCIES[4].value,
          JPY: value * CURRENCIES[3].value / CURRENCIES[5].value,
          GBP: value * CURRENCIES[3].value / CURRENCIES[6].value
        });
        break;

      case "CAD":
        this.setState({
          MXN: value * CURRENCIES[4].value,
          USD: value * CURRENCIES[4].value / CURRENCIES[1].value,
          USDFix: value * CURRENCIES[4].value / CURRENCIES[2].value,
          EUR: value * CURRENCIES[4].value / CURRENCIES[3].value,
          CAD: value,
          JPY: value * CURRENCIES[4].value / CURRENCIES[5].value,
          GBP: value * CURRENCIES[4].value / CURRENCIES[6].value
        });
        break;

      case "JPY":
        this.setState({
          MXN: value * CURRENCIES[5].value,
          USD: value * CURRENCIES[5].value / CURRENCIES[1].value,
          USDFix: value * CURRENCIES[5].value / CURRENCIES[2].value,
          EUR: value * CURRENCIES[5].value / CURRENCIES[3].value,
          CAD: value * CURRENCIES[5].value / CURRENCIES[4].value,
          JPY: value,
          GBP: value * CURRENCIES[5].value / CURRENCIES[6].value
        });
        break;

      case "GBP":
        this.setState({
          MXN: value * CURRENCIES[6].value,
          USD: value * CURRENCIES[6].value / CURRENCIES[1].value,
          USDFix: value * CURRENCIES[6].value / CURRENCIES[2].value,
          EUR: value * CURRENCIES[6].value / CURRENCIES[3].value,
          CAD: value * CURRENCIES[6].value / CURRENCIES[4].value,
          JPY: value * CURRENCIES[6].value / CURRENCIES[5].value,
          GBP: value
        });
        break;

      default:
        this.setState({
          MXN: value,
          USD: value / CURRENCIES[1].value,
          USDFix: value / CURRENCIES[2].value,
          EUR: value / CURRENCIES[3].value,
          CAD: value / CURRENCIES[4].value,
          JPY: value / CURRENCIES[5].value,
          GBP: value / CURRENCIES[6].value
        });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {CURRENCIES.map(currency => (
          <SingleInput
            type="text"
            maxLength={12}
            key={currency.name}
            name={currency.name}
            placeholder={`${currency.name} ${currency.value || ""}` || "MXN"}
            value={this.state[`${currency.name}`] || ""}
            onChange={this.handleCurrencyInput}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `handleCurrencyInput` the formula is always converted = value * inputcurrencyrate / outputcurrencyrate;

The two special cases MXN, and identity (eg USD -> USD) still follow the equation if you set MXN to 1

So if you structure CURRENCIES as a dict instead of an array you can simplify to

```
const CURRENCIES = {
  MXN: 1,
  USD: fetchedCurrencies[0]["bm:Obs"][0].$.OBS_VALUE,
  USDFix: fetchedCurrencies[1]["bm:Obs"][0].$.OBS_VALUE,
  EUR: fetchedCurrencies[2]["bm:Obs"][0].$.OBS_VALUE,
  CAD: fetchedCurrencies[3]["bm:Obs"][0].$.OBS_VALUE,
  JPY: fetchedCurrencies[4]["bm:Obs"][0].$.OBS_VALUE,
  GBP: fetchedCurrencies[5]["bm:Obs"][0].$.OBS_VALUE
};

...

handleCurrencyInput = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const newState = {};
    for (const currency in CURRENCIES) {
        this.setState({[currency]: value * (CURRENCIES[name] / CURRENCIES[currency])})
    }
}
```

And adding additional currencies is trivial

Adapted render:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(CURRENCIES).map(currency => (
        <SingleInput
          type="text"
          maxLength={12}
          key={currency}
          name={currency}
          placeholder={`${currency} ${CURRENCIES[currency] || ""}` || "MXN"}
          value={this.state[`${currency}`] || ""}
          onChange={this.handleCurrencyInput}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is a dict basically an object? or what is the difference?

Comment: Yes, just an simple object

Comment: So I encountered a problem with the way I'm using `.map()` on `CURRENCIES` if you see the codebox example you can see what I'm talking about, any ideas how to solve this considering that?
I know i can use `Object.keys(CURRENCIES).map()` but it doesn't let me input decimal points wouldn't know if it's related though, just an observation.

Comment: I added an updated render, I'm not sure what decimal point issue you're encountering.

Comment: So there are two cases:
Trying to use a decimal point as in 15.50 and also numbers like 15 triggers some kind of bug on currencies different from MXN.
I adapted the sandbox with your code and it replicates the problem

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oqmjwpyxrq)

Comment: Changing the input type to number aka `<SingleInput type="number"` fixed the input issue for me.  Also imo they look nicer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76942/discussion-between-ricardonava-and-generalhenry).